# Mapreduce cannot sort by value [python]

Tags: python, json, hadoop, mapreduce, mapper

Purpose is to sort (key, value) by value of the input, which is a json file. I have 4 methods, two pairs of mappers and reducers.

Input is similar to

```
{ 
  id: 1, 
  user: {
    friends_count: 1
  } 
}
```

Output of first stage of mapper and reducer is something like

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
D 4
```

What i want is

```
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
```

In the first stage sort by key works fine, but at the second stage where i try to make value the key, an error is thrown which says

> TypeError:  at 0x7fa43ea615a0> is not JSON serializable

The code which i am using is

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
from mrjob.step import MRStep
import json

class MRFrnsCounter(MRJob):
    def steps(self):
        return [
            MRStep(mapper=self.mapper,
                   reducer=self.reducer),
            MRStep(mapper = self.mapper_two,
                    reducer = self.reducer_two)
        ]

def mapper(self, _, line):
    f = json.loads(line)
    (uid, frns) = f["id"],f["user"]["friends_count"]
    yield (uid), (frns)

def reducer(self, uid, frns):
    yield uid, sum(frns)

def mapper_two(self, uid, frns):
    yield (frns), (uid)

def reducer_two(self, frns, uid):
    yield (frns), uid

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MRFrnsCounter.run()
```

The code breaks in the second mapper when the key and value are reversed. Any opinions would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this: `TypeError: at 0x7fa43ea615a0> is not JSON serializable` really the full error message?

Comment: Sorry. The full error message is 

**TypeError: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7efbfe824a50> is not JSON serializable**

Comment: post the full error message with the stack trace. What is `line`? I'm pretty sure you need to materialize that generator in `mapper`.

Comment: please see my comment below

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `yield sum(frns), uid` in the first reducer?

However, in your second mapper you are trying to yield a generator, not an integer. Iterate through the generator to yield frns, uid. Something like this:

```
for num in frns:
    yield num, uid
```

Comment: i tired that, but i read somewhere that reversing the keys should happen in the second stage. However, i am presented with the same error.

Comment: In mapper_two, you are trying to yield the generator object, which is not json serializable. You need to iterate through the generator in order to yield frns, uid. See the above edit.

Comment: i changed the second reducer to 

`def reducer_two(self, frns, uid):

        for num in frns:

            yield num, uid`

But now it throws the error 

 **TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable**

Comment: However, if i make uid as key, it sorts the output but in a very strange fashion.

uid, 1

uid, 123

uid, 13

uid, 235

uid, 28

and so on.. i'm confused as to what is happening under the hood.

Comment: MapReduce does not sort reducer output. Try here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322381/mapreduce-job-output-sort-order